# use WPP from user mode application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, logging, etw

I try to use WPP under user mode, managed to successfully use it in VS10, Release target by adding to the proj file:

```
    <PropertyGroup><WdkDir>c:\work\Proj\wppTest\DDK\</WdkDir><MyTargetsDir>c:\work\Proj\wppTest</MyTargetsDir>  </PropertyGroup>

...

  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
    <Import Project="$(MyTargetsDir)\Wpp.targets" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

Then Wpp.targets is defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
      <ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean>$(ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean);*.tmh</ExtensionsToDeleteOnClean>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <CoreCppClean Include="@(CoreCppClean);$(ProjectDir)">
          <FilePatternsToDelete>*.tmh</FilePatternsToDelete>
     </CoreCppClean>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <TraceWppSources Include="@(ClCompile)" Exclude="stdafx.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="TraceWpp" BeforeTargets="ClCompile" Inputs="@(TraceWppSources)" Outputs="@(TraceWppSources -> '%(Filename).tmh')">
    <Exec Command="cd $(ProjectDir)" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Creating tmh"/>
    <Exec Command="$(WdkDir)\bin\x86\tracewpp.EXE -cfgdir:$(WdkDir)\bin\wppconfig\rev1 -odir:. @(TraceWppSources, ' ')" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="tmh created"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

This steps were taken from article: http://www.devproconnections.com/article/visual-studio-2010/wpp-tracing-in-visual-c-2010-projects

When trying to compile this under VS10->Debug I can see that "tmh" files are being generated only that I get error when actualy I want to log something:

DoTraceMessage(TRACE_ERROR, L"Aha"); //  error C2065: 'TRACE_ERROR' : undeclared identifier error C3861: 'WPP_CALL_Application_Test_cpp': identifier not found

As I've said I have no issues with the same code on VS10->Release target. Here is my defines for reference:

```
#pragma once

#define WPP_CONTROL_GUIDS \
    WPP_DEFINE_CONTROL_GUID(CtlGuid,(28EE579B, CF67, 43b6, 9D19, 8930E7AAA131),  \
                                                                            \
        WPP_DEFINE_BIT(TRACE_ERROR)                                   \
        WPP_DEFINE_BIT(TRACE_WARNING)                                   \
        WPP_DEFINE_BIT(TRACE_INFO1)                                   \
        WPP_DEFINE_BIT(TRACE_INFO2)                                   \
        )
```

Does anyone have any idea why that might work using Release mode but does not work under Debug mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that when you compile with the "Debug symbols in PDB with Edit & Continue support" the compiler does not resolve the __LINE__ macro.

The WPP compiler defines a function WPP_CALL_Application_Test_cpp51 if you trace from Application_Test.cpp line 51, and uses __FILE__ and __LINE__ to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason why it was not compiling on DEBUG mode. I had the /ZI compiler flag ([1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx)) set and it was expecting the /Zi format for compiling to work in Debug.